Necessity of universal quantifier to represent a theorem with logic symbols
I have a preference to reduce the proof steps of a theorem, and the theorem itself, into logic symbols as much as possible. Not just because it is aesthetically appealing, but because it makes makes things simpler and faster when studying, or when one wants to write down any proposition without excess. Since i started doing it, i've been synthesizing any mathematical proposition into a lot of implications and parentheses. But, recently, i started having some doubts about its validity under rigorous criteria, specially about the usage of the universal quantifier. For example, if i want to represent the proposition of the sentence "THE SQUARE OF A REAL NUMBER IS ALWAYS POSITIVE",usually we denote it as $\forall x\in\mathbb{R},x^2>0$. But the sentence in common language that we utilize to represent that proposition does not say "FOR ALL REAL NUMBERS, their square is positive". Despite the fact that it means exactly the same, it seems that we could represent this propostion without lossing it's sentence subtlety provided by common language like this: $x \in \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow x^2>0$.
My questions are the following: does that last expression covers all the real numbers? Is it equivalent to the first expression? Can the the proposition "THE SQUARE OF A REAL NUMBER IS ALWAYS POSITIVE" be signified by $x \in \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow x^2>0$ or not?
I know that the use of $x \in \mathbb{R}$ makes of x an arbitrary real number, i.e, x is free to vary over the domain of the discourse defined as $\mathbb{R}$, but it is has the same value that the x after the implication, so it has a fixed value for all the intermediate propositions in the formula despite assuming any value to start. For me they are equivalent since the implication assumes the antecedent to be true and, due to the fact that it is true to and infinity number of objects, it covers all the real numbers. To resume: looks like it is not necessary to quantify this sentence with the universal quantifier since we used a variable in the antecedent and can assume any value over the real numbers.

Sorry for the grammar mistakes!


$(\forall x\in A)P(x)$ is just a usual abreviation for $(\forall x)((x\in A)\to P(x))$.

@AnneBauval But if that is so, my domain of discourse could not be $\Bbb R$, Right? What would be it so? It would depend on the context or i would have to work with other concepts of number as contemplated by $\Bbb C$, since it contains the reals, right?

@Davi1399 Read my Answer. A logic expression is just that: a logic expression. It does not define any kind of domain. It is only when you interpret a sentence that you specify a domain. Different interpretations can specify different domains for the same sentence. And that's the point and beauty of logic: a logical theorem like $\forall x (P(x) \lor \neg P(x))$ is something that is true, no matter the domain.

IMO the best discussion is still Bertrand Russell, Mathematical Logic as based on the Theory of Types (1908): II All and Any for the clear discussion of the interplay between Instantiation and Generalization.

David, I'd say the domain of discourse is 'the' whole universe (i.e. a model of set-theory).

@MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you for bringing this reference, in fact, i think it goes direct to the point.

You still need a universal. Indeed, technically $x \in \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow x^2>0$ is a well-formed formula, but it is not a sentence to which you can assign a truth-value.  It is only to a sentence like $\exists x (x \in \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow x^2>0)$ that we can assign a truth-value ... and note that this sentence obviously not equivalent to the one you want, which is $\forall x (x \in \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow x^2>0)$
Now, some texts do leave out the universal, and use expressions like $x \in \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow x^2>0$. However, this is just short-hand for $\forall x (x \in \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow x^2>0)$. Indeed, the expression $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} : \ x^2>0$ is itself short-hand for $\forall x (x \in \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow x^2>0)$.
In fact, logic expressions themselves do not specify any kind of domain. That is left to interpretations of those sentences. Indeed, logic expressions not specifying any domain is kind of the point of logic: logic is something that is supposed to cut across different domains and worlds.

I disagree that the formula with no quantifier is "just short-hand" for the version with the quantifier. A standard rule of logic is that if one can prove $P(a)$, where $a$ is a free variable not appearing in $P$, then one can conclude $\forall x. P(x)$.  For example, this is exactly the $\forall$-introduction rule of natural deduction.   So there is something going on here that your answer is leaving out.

@MJD  But that is in the context of a formal proof system. The OP is talking about a stand-alone expression to express some mathematical statement. Or if it is used in a proof, at least a statement that is used a premise or a conclusion, but not something that occurs in the middle of a proof.  I was talking about the practice of some books to express, say, the Peano Axioms as $x + 0 = x$. And in that context it really is just short-hand for $\forall x \ x+0=x$

If the inference didn't make sense in informal logic, it wouldn't make sense in a formal proof system. The whole point of a formal proof system is to codify the rules we use in ordinary reasoning with natural language. So OP is on to something here that I think your explanation omits.

@MJD I still don’t see how the fact that some formal proof systems allow for open statements has to do with the fundamental nature of OP’s question, which is really just about how to express some claim in the language of logic. So, I don’t think the OP is ‘on to something’ here at all. In fact, the OP is now saying that they want to regard the $\Rightarrow$ in their expression as a meta-logical symbol of logical consequence, so the OP is really just confused.

@ Bram28 I agree with you, but i think i omitted some fundamental points in my question that relies upon what @MJD said. I'm gonna create a new thread and try to clarify my ideas a little bit better.

The expression $x \in \mathbb{R} \implies x^2 \geq0 $ can be interpreted as :"if $x$ is a real number, then $x^2 \geq0$". This expression appears to cover all real numbers, but it depends on the context and the way we interpret $x$. It implicitly suggests that $x$ is a real number and that $x^2 \geq0$ holds. However , it's not standard in formal logic because it lacks explicit quantifiers.
What I mean is that the expression $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}
,x^2 \geq0$ can be stated alone and make sense no matter the context while the other one can't.
One example I can think is : if $f(x)=x^2$ solve the equation $f(x)>-1$
We have $x\in\mathbb{R}
\implies x^2\geq0\implies x^2>-1$ Therefore $f(x)>-1 ,\forall x\in\mathbb{R}
$

I disagree that the expression $x \in \mathbb{R} \implies x^2 \geq0 $  implicitly suggests that $x$ is a real number. I would say that it  explicitly suggests it, because that is exactly the antecedent. But one might also interpret it as being a statement about potatoes, with a vacuous antecedent.  (Every potato that is an element of the real numbers has a nonnegative square.)  In any case adding the quantifier does not seem to me to affect this, whatever interpretation you take.
